# Should I nest a var element in a code element?

Tags: html

The HTML spec states that you should contain your code samples in `<code></code>` elements.
An example would be:

```
<code>
   alert('hello world');
</code>
```

It also states that you should contain variables in `<var></var>` elements.
An example would be:

```
<p>
   A simple equation:
   <var>a</var> = <var>b</var> + 2;
</p>
```

What if I have a variable inside the code block?

```
<code>
   a = 10;
   alert('a = ' + a);
</code>
```

Is it going to be like this?

```
<code>
   <var>a</var> = 10;
   alert('a = ' + <var>a</var>);
</code>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your choice whether you want to wrap it with the tag or not. there won't be any visual difference, however you like to do it.But for bot's and screen readers i'll have some special meanings. So if you need to enrich you document with proper tags, you can. It'll do without excess markups!